# Memory leak with Curl and OpenSSL

Tags: c, curl, memory-leaks, openssl

I am getting serious memory leak while using Curl (7.33.0) and OpenSSL (1.0.1e). I have reached 2GB of memory easily. Reproduced in every machine I checked, Win 7, Win8.

This is part of a multi-threaded application that I am developing.

```
myRetCode UploadFile(nschar_t *pPath, nschar_t *local_path)
{
    CURL        *curl = NULL;
    CURLcode    res = CURLE_OK;
    nsuint_t    http_code = 0;
    nschar_t    url[URL_LENGTH];
    nschar_t    errMsg[ERROR_SIZE];
    myRetCode   rc = OK_SUCCESS;
    curl_off_t  fsize;
    FILE        *fp;
    struct stat file_info;

    sprintf_s(url, sizeof(url), "https://mysite?",  pPath);

    fp = fopen(local_path, "rb");
    if(!fp)
    {
        return NS_FAILURE;
    }

    /* to get the file size */
    if(fstat(fileno(fp), &file_info) != 0)
    {
        return NS_FAILURE; /* can't continue */
    }
    fsize = (curl_off_t)stFileInfo.ulFileSize;

    curl = curl_easy_init();
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "xyz");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1L);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 0L);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS, 1L);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_NOSIGNAL, 1L);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_ERRORBUFFER, errMsg);

    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_UPLOAD, 1L);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_READFUNCTION, UploadFile_Data);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_READDATA, fp);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_INFILESIZE_LARGE, (curl_off_t)file_info.st_size);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");

    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
    if(res != CURLE_OK)
    {
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
        fclose(fp);
        return MY_CURL_LIB_ERROR;
    }

    curl_easy_getinfo(curl, CURLINFO_RESPONSE_CODE, &http_code);
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    RC = SUCCESS;

    fclose(fp);
    return rc;
}

size_t UploadFile_Data(char *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *userp)
{
    size_t read;
    read = fread(ptr, size, nmemb, userp);
    return read;
}
```

I have done memory debugging with  `_CrtDumpMemoryLeaks()`. It shows leaks around:

```
res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
curl = curl_easy_init();
```

and anything that has CURL calls.

I have read lot of posts where there is a discussion around possible memory leaks while using OpenSSL with Curl but with no definite answer. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: "This is part of a multi-threaded application that i am developing." - OpenSSL cleanup can be tricky in multi-threaded applications. You have your standard leaks from, for example, `ssl_comp_methods`. Then, to clean up each thread's error queue with `ERR_remove_state`. You might also benefit from `SSL_MODE_RELEASE_BUFFERS`, but be sure to apply the patch at [OpenSSL fails if used from multiple threads and with SSL_MODE_RELEASE_BUFFERS](https://rt.openssl.org/Ticket/Display.html?id=2167&user=guest&pass=guest).

Comment: @jww Thanks. I have gone through Curl code and `ERR_remove_state` is implemented in ssluse.c on function void `Curl_ossl_cleanup(void)`. The commenting says its part of Global Cleanup. So i assume this will be called on `curl_global_cleanup`. Do i need to do anything explicitly on my thread routines ?

Comment: curl_easy_init() followed by curl_easy_cleanup() on the handle should not leak memory. You're either experiencing a bug or the leak is not caused by libcurl at all...

Comment: @DanielStenberg Thank you. I am pretty sure that i always call `curl_easy_cleanup()` after 'curl_easy_init()` from the same thread. Kindly let me know if you need more information

Comment: if it happened to me, I would use a tool to figure out where exactly the leak was - but then I don't run Windows...

Comment: @DanielStenberg. I will run memory leak program once again and report the findings. I am using a thread pool where the thread gets used again and again for each job. Inside each job i do a init and cleanup before returning the thread to the threadpool. Does this cause issue or do i need to discard the threads after each job and create new threads for individual jobs without reusing the threads?

Comment: You should be able to reuse the same threads. curl_easy_init/curl_easy_cleanup are per-curl handle, and so long as they aren't crossing thread boundaries (and probably then too, though I've never tried) it should be fine. It would be near-trivial to setup a simple pack of threads that spin N times performing that duo for a minute or so (see how many you can squeeze in on each thread in 60 seconds) then signal the threads to finish and cleanup, and check the CRT debug report. I've used lib curl for something similar to your apparent purpose without issue. IOCP's btw, make this.. interesting.

Comment: Not a help with the memory issue, but you have a potential file handle leak in this if block:   if(fstat(fileno(fp), &file_info) != 0)

Add a fclose(fp).

Comment: Apparently after lot of debugging it turned out that the memory leak was not cURL's fault. Elsewhere in the chain i was leaking some memory. Thanks for all the help. cURL rocks!!